# Ionic Firebase using .on with a promise does not return edited values

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to figure out how to get firebase database information from a provider to a page/component using a Promise while still using firebase's `.on`.  This is currently not showing updated edited values.

I have my database provider here:

```
getEvents() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afDatabase.database.ref('events/').on('value', success => {
            resolve(success.val());
        }, error => {
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}
```

And grabbing it in my component here:

```
getEvents() {
    this.firebaseDatabase.getEvents().then(success => {
        this.events = <Array<Object>> success;
        console.log(success);
    }, error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

If I were to just use firebase's `.on` it works fine, but passing it to the component with a promise does not work for me.

I don't need to use `Promise`, but I don't know "the right" way to do it.  I'm sure I need to use `Observable`s, but I'm deep into looking for it.

Comment: Why can't you use `once()`, which already returns a Promise?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Would that update the objects when a change is made in the database?  I think my problem is using a promise with the on, rather than once with a promise

Comment: A promise can only resolve once, which is precisely the reason Firebase doesn't return a promise from `on()`. In your code, the promise will resolve immediately (if a connection is available or a value is cached). Then once a change comes in, it will fail.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, so, is it possible that I'd rather use an observer?

Comment: Sorry. I'm afraid I don't understand your last question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I've just figured out the best way to do this.  I was stuck in my old ways, but now I'm using `.on` correctly with a `ReplaySubject()`. Coincidentally I just read another one of your answers about data denormalization which helped me a lot

Comment: Great to hear Nathan!